# Bluetooth Dongle not automatically Pairing with BlueSmirf

Tags: boot, bluetooth, services

I've setup Bluetooth on my RaspPi and attempted to connect to my BlueSmirf from Sparkfun.

I can send text to my BlueSmirf from the RaspberryPi using:

```
echo "Testing" > /dev/rfcomm0
```

Now the red led on my BlueSmirf indicates its not paired with a device, only when I use `cat /dev/rfcomm0` the raspberryPi will start a Pairing session with the BlueSmirf (and the led turns green).

I now can send and receive text from both sides, the problem is that I manually need to invoke `cat /dev/rfcomm0`. I would like that the RaspberryPi looks for my BlueSmirf at startup and starts a pairing session automatically.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ha found the solution, first and all in the rfcomm.conf set the bind option to no. this solves a lot of problems. Next you use the rfcomm command to start a connection.

For example:
**rfcomm connect 0**
Will open a connection using the configuration of rfcomm0. You can send this to the background, so its always connected using the following command:

```
rfcomm connect 0 &> /dev/null 2> /dev/null &
```

To close a connection you use the following command **rfcomm release 0**

Answer (score 1):

I've seen a new Bluetooth solution for our Raspis.  There are 2 versions, you can find them [here](http://www.cooking-hacks.com/index.php/documentation/tutorials/bluetooth-module-pro-for-raspberry-pi) and [here](http://www.cooking-hacks.com/index.php/documentation/tutorials/raspberry-pi-bluetooth). Have you tried it?

I own a pub and I was looking for a contest using Bluetooth and mobile phones. I think this PRO solution can be great to manage the contest with my Raspi.